# Algunos elementos de RecyclerView desaparecen a dar Scroll

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview

estoy creando una aplicacion en Android Studio que trata del monitoreo de sensores, la informacion de los sensores la recibo de un arduino conectado a un modulo wifi HLK-RM04 configurado con una direccion ip estatica y un puerto, por medio de Socket e InputStream logro obtener la cadena de datos que es mas o menos asi:

"1,23.44,5.43:2,23.43,4.43:3,28.45:5.21:4,23.53,5.23:"
esta cadema la recibo cada 4 segundos por lo que requiero que el recyclerview actualice su vista

este es mi adaptador

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<String> dataSoucer;
private RecyclerView.Adapter variantAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager variantLayoutManager;


public myAdapter(List<String> dataSoucer) {
    this.dataSoucer = dataSoucer;
}

public void inserData(List<String> insertList){
    MyDiffUtilCallback callback=new MyDiffUtilCallback(dataSoucer,insertList);
    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult= DiffUtil.calculateDiff(callback);
    dataSoucer.addAll(insertList);
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
public void updateData(List<String> newtList){
   MyDiffUtilCallback callback=new MyDiffUtilCallback(dataSoucer,newtList);
    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult= DiffUtil.calculateDiff(callback);
    dataSoucer.clear();
    dataSoucer.addAll(newtList);

    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    myViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    String cadena=dataSoucer.get(i);
    String[] reparto=cadena.split(",");
    myViewHolder.estanque.setText(reparto[0]);
    myViewHolder.temperatura.setText(reparto[1]);
    myViewHolder.oxigeno.setText(reparto[2]);

   // notifyDataSetChanged();


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSoucer.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView estanque,temperatura,oxigeno;
    TextView name_estanque,name_temperatura,name_oxigeno;
    private RecyclerView recicler;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name_estanque=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_estanque);
        name_temperatura=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_temperatura);
        name_oxigeno=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_oxigeno);
        estanque=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.estanque);
        temperatura=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.temperatura);
        oxigeno=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.oxigeno);

    }
}
```

como pueden ver tengo un metodo que actualiza pero en la vista del recycler view al dar un poco scroll algunos elemtos desaparecen, en cuenta que tengo un Thread funcionando cada 3 segundos y esto haria que reciba los datos por medio de socket y los pase al adaptador y dibuje en el recyclerview

Este es mi ActivityMain

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<String> datasourcer=new ArrayList<>();
private int contador_prueba=1;
private myAdapter adapter;
private NestedScrollView nested;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


     adapter=new myAdapter(datasourcer);
     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator(); if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) { ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false); }
    new Thread(new Client()).start();

}

 public void setPlayersDataAdapter(){
    int contar_temp=1;

    contador_prueba+=1;
    String contar_temp2=String.valueOf(contador_prueba);

    String cadena="1,"+contar_temp2+",5.32,:2,34.23,5.22,:3,23.23,4.32,:4,24.21,5.12,:5,23.56,6.78,:6,21.34,6.45,:7,45.34,7.23,:";
    String[] cadena2=cadena.split(":");

    int contador_for=cadena2.length;
    List<String> update=new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        int contador_array=0;

        for (int i=0;i<=contador_for;i++){
            update.add(cadena2[i]);
            adapter.updateData(update);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




        }
        contador_prueba+=1;
        // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();






    }catch (Exception e){

    }










}



class Client extends Thread {

    public void run()
    {
        //List<Player> players=new ArrayList<>();

        int contar_temp=1;
        try
        {

            while (true) {




                setPlayersDataAdapter();
                sleep(4000);



            }



        }
        catch(Exception e) {}






    }
}
```

disculpen por el desastre pero estoy haciendo pruebas con una cadena y una variable incrementable, mi problema es que al dar un poco de scroll en la vista del recycler me elimina algunos elementos y despues de recibir otra cadena de datos me los añade pero aun asi faltan algunos elementos, en verdad no se si sea la mejor forma con recyclerview, tomando en cuenta que la aplicacion es para monitorear por eso actualizo cada 3 segundos el adaptador

`

Comment: Has quitado el animator para confirmar que no sea eso?

Comment: He quitado de todo, he hecho muchas pruebas y me sigue dando el mismo problema, el adaptador se actualiza cada 4 segundos con un nuevo arraylist y llamo a notifyDataChanged() y si hace el cambio pero al dar un poco de scroll mientras actualiza de nuevo es cuando se pierden algunos elementos pero en la siguiente vuelta del ciclo me vuelve a mostrar todos los elementos